# Ignite SQL Queries are not returning data when trying to join the tables with huge data or directly filter table with huge data

Tags: c#, ignite

Ignite is in AWS K8s, three node Cluster,4GB RAM and 3 Cores each node.

We are using C# thick client hosted as the container in the same AWS K8s
JVM options we have for thick client node is RAM  Initial 2GB, Max 4GB, Cores initial 0.5 , max 2

we have two Caches, Table1- with  1.6Million records, Table2 -150Million records.
In this case we are using AffinityKey and its colocated.

when trying to query Table1 getting the data but when trying to get the data from table2 its not returning data.

one more issues is when multiple users are trying to query, even not getting the data from table1 also.

Comment: Do you mean that the query doesn't finish or it fails with an error? Also, do you see any error messages in the server logs?

Comment: @IgorBelyakov  we did not observe any errors and tried to execute the same query from SQL Line and observed that it has taken around 760 sec. and during the multi user scenario we have observed error [13:52:25,766][SEVERE][tcp-disco-msg-worker-[22a660bf 10.53.103.74:47500 crd]-#2-#58][G] Blocked system-critical thread has been detected. This can lead to cluster-wide undefined behaviour [workerName=disco-event-worker, threadName=disco-event-worker-#64, blockedFor=138s]